# Google api for autocomplete places "types" issue

Tags: autocomplete, google-places-api

I used google places autocomplete API which is working fine but i want to restrict search result to specific places , postcodes,stores,malls only . search result should not return city names , or town names. but i am not able to restrict this.

Comment: Since you're asking other coders wouldn't this question make more sense with the relevant code included?

Comment: What you are trying so far that isn't working for you?